# Temporary file with specific file extension in Python 3

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x, file-extension, temporary-files

I am writing some unit tests for a piece of code that takes a path and attempts to load the file if it has a known extension, then does more careful checking.

In the unit test, I would like to create a temporary file that has the correct extension, but incorrect contents, in my case an empty file posing as `test.tif`.

How can I create a temporary file while specifying the extension (or the entire name), using the `tempfile` module?

I have looked at the `NamedTemporaryFile` class, as well as the `suffix` and `prefix` parameters, but I still cannot set the extension. I suppose I could manually create a file in a temporary directory, but then I loose the self-deleting capability that I am after.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

This doesn't work for you?

```
In [2]: tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.tif').name
Out[2]: '/var/folders/gq/swc6jtld5853skyq_xc2lpc40000gn/T/tmplrtwvxg7.tif'
```

Answer (score 3):

did you try?

```
fd, path =tempfile.mkstemp(suffix = '.tif')
print(path)
```

Comment: Please try to add some explanation about the code.