# How to create an image from binary data returned by a request to store and use in Django app?

Tags: python, django, dropbox-api

I am using the `Dropbox API Explorer - get_thumbnail` to get a thumbnail of images stored following the [get_thumbnail documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_thumbnail)

The response returns a blob in binary. I am attempting to create a image file to store as an `imagefield` on my django app's database.

I followed [this Quickstart](https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) to create the image.

```py
# get_thumbnail request
url = "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_thumbnail"

# product_path is a variable storing path from list_folder
new_product_path = "{\"path\":\"/%s\"}" %(product_path)
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer <api_token_ommitted>",
    "Dropbox-API-Arg": new_product_path
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers)

thumbnail = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))

# album is foreign key for Album model
product = Product.objects.create(album=album, name=converted_name, image=converted_url, thumbnail=thumbnail)
print('Product has been created!')
```

The results of `print(r.content)`:

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x06\x04\x05\x06\x05\x04\x06\x06\x05\x06\x07\x07\x06\x08\n\x10\n\n\t\t\n\x14\x0e\x0f\x0c\x10\x17\x14\x18\x18\x17\x14\x16\x16\x1a\x1d%\x1f\x1a\x1b#\x1c\x16\x16 , #&\')*)\x19\x1f-0-(0%()(\xff\xdb\x00C\x01\x07\x07\x07\n\x08\n\x13\n\n\x13(\x1a\x16\x1a((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((\xff\xc0\x00\x11\x08\x00$\x00@\x03\x01"\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x01\x05\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\xff\xc4\x00\xb5\x10\x00\x02\x01\x03\x03\x02\x04\x03\x05\x05\x04\x04\x00\x00\x01}\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x11\x05\x12!1A\x06\x13Qa\x07"q\x142\x81\x91\xa1\x08#B\xb1\xc1\x15R\xd1\xf0$3br\x82\t\n\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a%&\'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xff\xc4\x00\x1f\x01\x00\x03\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\xff\xc4\x00\xb5\x11\x00\x02\x01\x02\x04\x04\x03\x04\x07\x05\x04\x04\x00\x01\x02w\x00\x01\x02\x03\x11\x04\x05!1\x06\x12AQ\x07aq\x13"2\x81\x08\x14B\x91\xa1\xb1\xc1\t#3R\xf0\x15br\xd1\n\x16$4\xe1%\xf1\x17\x18\x19\x1a&\'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xff\xda\x00\x0c\x03\x01\x00\x02\x11\x03\x11\x00?\x00\xfa\x16\x8a\xc3_\x15h\xcd\x1c\x8c\xb7\xa8v\x9cm\xc1\x05\xbe\x80\xf5\xa7\xc3\xe2m\x1eB\xa0\xea6\xf1\x92\xa5\xb1+l \x0e\xb9\'\x8f\xd6\xbc\xa5R\r\xd93\xdcxj\xd1Wp\x7fs6h\xacx|K\xa2L3\x0e\xabg \xeb\xf2\xc9\x9a\xcd\xd6|w\xa3i\x9at\xd7m$\xb3\xac\\\x95\x8a2I\xa6\xe7\x14\xec\xd8G\rZ[A\xfd\xc7UEs\xd6\x9e0\xd1n,\x92\xe5\xaf\x16\x10\xc8\x1fd\xa0\x86\xc7\xb0\xefV-\xfcO\xa2\xcd\x07\x9a\xba\x9d\xa0PpCH\x14\x83\xee\x0f\xf3\xe9B\x9c_Pxj\xd1\xde\x0f\xeef\xcd\x15\x917\x894h@2j\x96x<\xe5d\r\xc7\xe1\x9ab\xf8\xa7B.\xe85{-\xeb\xc1\x1eg"\x9d\xd1>\xc2\xae\xfc\xaf\xeeg\xc2\xd3^\xddN\x00\x9a\xe2g\x00`\x06rq@\xbc\xb8\xe33\xc8p0>c\xd3\xd2\xa0\xa2\xbd\xbeT\xba\x18\xacMT\xef\xcc\xfe\xf3F\xcbX\xbb\xb4\x04C)Q\x90\xdcz\xd5\xa4\xf1>\xa6\xa1\xc7\xda\\\xab\x8c2\x93\xc1\xe75\x89EC\xa5\x07\xbaGB\xcc\xb1)[\x98\xd9\xb9\xf1\r\xf5\xc3\xc7#\xce\xfb\xd3\xa6\x0e1U\xe7\xd6/\'bd\x99\xc9 \x83\xcfPz\xd6u\x14\xd5(-\x90\xdeg\x89\x7fh\xb35\xed\xc4\xbc4\xcf\x8fL\xd4+,\x8ar\xae\xc0\xe7<\x1ae\x15VH\xe6\x9e&\xac\xdf4\xa4\xc2\x8a(\xa6b\x14QE\x00\x14QE\x00\x14QE\x00\x7f\xff\xd9'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to convert bytes data to image as follows, if your data in bytes format, I think following code will help you

```
bytes_data = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00'

with open("path/image.png", "wb") as f:
   f.write(bytes_data)
```

Add the new path of image to image field.
For more details refer following

- [How to generate temporary file in django and then destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619600/how-to-generate-temporary-file-in-django-and-then-destroy)
- [Temporary file with specific file extension in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900216/temporary-file-with-specific-file-extension-in-python-3)
- [Programmatically saving image to Django ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield)